# How can I download and install Logicmonitor collector installer on ec2 instance from userdata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

Logicmonitor collector installers must be fetched with a valid token and the installer expires after a period of time.  So there's no simple way to pull a collector installer binary onto a new ec2 instance and then run it.

Instead, it is necessary to use a script which uses Logicmonitor's REST API to generate a new collector installer URL, then fetch that and run it immediately.  I'm guessing that, since there is a logicmonitor provider in terraform, at least one other person has gone through this process and already has a working script.  Frankly, Logicmonitor's docs provide the bulk of it, so it isn't that hard to generate for myself, but if someone out there already has a nice template or module which adds the necessary pieces to an instance's userdata, you'll save me a couple of hours of copypasta and trial and error work.  Something that uses cloud-init would be particularly useful, but I can convert.  Basic example:

```
runcmd:
  - export COLLECTOR_URL = `get_collector_url.sh ${api_key} ${other_var} ${yet_another}`
  - curl -o LogicmonitorCollector.bin $COLLECTOR_URL
  - chmod +x LogicmonitorCollector.bin
  - ./LogicmonitorCollector.bin
```

I can pull the script for get_collector_url.sh out of github or an S3 bucket in an earlier statement easily enough.

This is the kind of thing I'd love to eventually build into a resource in the logicmonitor provider.  I am new to terraform and don't know what is involved in adding a new resource, but this seems like a common need for anyone planning to bring up all of their infrastructure via terraform, since I don't want to have to manually install collectors on the instances terraform will be launching in my mgmt VPC for handling things like bastion duty and monitoring collectors.

Note - Logicmonitor claims the installer binary itself will expire after 2 hours.  I've been taking them at their word.  If what they actually mean it that the token in the installer URL will expire after 2 hours, I could just download the installer once and stick it in an AMI so that I need never download it again - just change the config to update collector id.  But I'm guessing there are reasons their docs don't provide instructions for just pulling the binary once.

Comment: can you download the bin file and save it to an s3 bucket? The user-data can fetch it easily.